# -su: /home/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner.bat: Permission denied

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I started working with sonarqube and getting stuck to get the code analyzed. Trying to add the properties of sonar in the source code file. By giving the following command

```
sonar-runner.bat
```

I am getting the error

> -su: /home/sonar-runner-2.4/bin/sonar-runner.bat: Permission denied

Any help at the earliest is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message and the name of your path, you seems to be using sonar-runner on Linux OS. In this case, you need to use `sonar-runner` without the bat extension.

Please note that you should use Sonar Scanner (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) which is the successor or Sonar Runner.